# Filter on features in a vector layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, arcgis-10.3

What I try to achieve is quite simple. I want to filter my vector layer by a query in the features. 
What I found out is that vector layer doesn't have `updateParams()` where I could do something like:

```
'layerDefs': featureName1+operatorName1+checkValue1
```

So is there an other way to achieve this? Cause now I`m kinda clueless on how to filter a vector layer.
Every way is welcome, the vector is already made so it's not a new vector layer.

I`m working with OpenLayers3 and ArcGIS featureservice.

I`m also not sure how to redraw the vector after it's filtered yet.
All of my vectors are saved in an array.

I tried everything but sadly i couldn't get it to work. this is what i tried in the end. Last try is underneath with help of the suggestion from @Alexis_A

Okay after some more testing i found the problem, for some reason it gives the name of my variable and not the value that contains my variable.
So in other words this bit of code:

```
var fn = featureName1;
console.log(fn);
var filtered = features.filter(function(feature) {
    console.log(feature);
    console.log(feature.values_.fn.value);
    return feature.values_.featureName1 == 2;
});
```

will littarly give this as console log:

> categorie_melding
>
> Object { pendingRemovals_: Object, dispatching_: Object, listeners_:
>   Object, revision_: 2, ol_uid: 90, values_: Object, id_: 158816,
>   geometryName_: "geometry", style_: null, styleFunction_: undefined, 2
>   meer… }
>
> TypeError: feature.values_.fn is undefined[Meer info]

So at first it knows what the variable should be, but when i`m in the filter function it's just clueless. Anyone any idea on how to fix this?

---

*And why is filtering in OpenLayers3 so hard i just can't understand that they dont have an easier way to do it.*

Answer (score 1):

Well it took me some time but i managed to make a sort of a working filter on vectorSource but it works for like half a second then it get's back to normal again. The code i used for that is this:

```
var vectorSource = mapLayersArray[0].getSource();
var features = vectorSource.getFeatures();
var filtered = features.filter(function(feature) {
    //console.log(feature.values_);
    return feature.values_[featureName1] == checkWaarde1;
});
vectorSource.clear();
var length = filtered.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    vectorSource.addFeature(filtered[i])
}
```

But as said it shows the filter for only like half a second for some(update,refresh,panning,zooming) reason i`m not sure of why.