# Is there a way to filter vector layer with JSON source in OL3?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, filter, vector-layer

Is it possible to filter the ol.layer.Vector with a JSON source and display only specific features?

My vector layer looks like this:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'http://vagrant-test.local.com/json/countries.js'
      }),
      style: function(feature) {
        return style;
      }
  });
```

I check the ol3 [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) and didn't find some filter functionality.

Comment: Maybe you can use a custom loader where you can filter the features in the source. See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/223412/8673

Comment: what would be the filter condition?

Comment: To show specific features base on an existing attribute/value. Eg.a date

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to filter them within your style function. Then create a transparent style and according to your condition return transparentStyle or style (you have feature with options within your style function). That means that your features will be loaded but will not be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create your own filter. You can do this by getting the JSON via ajax:

```
var jsonResult;

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
       jsonResult = data;
    }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Then you will need to delete the elements you do not want from jsonResult, and re-stringify it. You'll need to be somewhat familiar with the structure of the GeoJSON data you're working with, GeoJSON in general so you don't delete something OL needs to parse it, and working with JSON.

Then you can read the remaining elements into features and add them to your source:

```
var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(stringifiedFilteredJSON);
layerSource.addFeatures(features);
```